# Insert PDF image with wide ratio without inserting empty page

Tags: includegraphics

I want to insert a PDF image on a unique page with only a section title and make it a bit bigger than the normal margin is allowing since I have space.

Here is the structure of the chapter (in the appendix), the document class is *report* (A4):

```latex
\chapter{\Y's Hardware}
\section{General Diagram}

\section{Bill of Material}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Component         & Ref. & Qty & Characteristics                                                  \\ \hline
Raspberry Pi 4B   &      & 2   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}8 GB (RAM)\\ 32 GB (µSD)\end{tabular} \\ \hline
Ultrasonic sensor &      &     &                                                                  \\ \hline
                  &      &     &                                                                  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\newpage
\section{Final PCB Circuit Diagram}
\centerline{\includegraphics[angle=90, width=1.1\linewidth]{image/apx/circuit.pdf}}

\newpage
\section{Final PCB Routing Diagram}
```

When I set the graphic size to `\linewidth` I don't have problems. But when I put `1.1\linewidth`, Latex inserts an empty page (with the page number) between the *Bill of Material* and *Final PCB Circuit Diagram* sections. I tried to remove the `\newpage`, but it doesn't change.

The PDF is a unique A4 page, and with a 1.1 ratio, it still fits between the section title and page number. Why LaTeX is inserting that empty page?

Comment: the image is too high. You can try \enlargethispage to make the current page larger. Or hide the height of the image by using e.g. `trim= 0cm 5cm 0cm 0cm`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with \enlargethispage{2\baselineskip} !